# How do Win32 executables display incompatibility messages when run in DOS?

Tags: windows, command-line, ms-dos, dosbox

While inspecting Win32 executables, I found them to contain the string `This program cannot be run in DOS mode`, which is exactly the thing printed when these executables are run from within DOS emulators such as DOSBox.

This leads me to the conclusion that the executable has two pathways - one is taken up by DOS (which causes the above message to be displayed), and another by Windows, which causes the main program to run.

How is this "two pathway" thing actually accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: every EXE file begins with a DOS executable.

Long answer:

> **The MS-DOS Header**
>
> Every PE file begins with a small MS-DOS® executable. The need for
>   this stub executable arose in the early days of Windows, before a
>   significant number of consumers were running it. When executed on a
>   machine without Windows, the program could at least print out a
>   message saying that Windows was required to run the executable.

Ref: February 2002 issue of MSDN Magazine Inside Windows - [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)

The Windows program loader just ignores this stub. DOS loads and runs it like it does any other DOS executable.